# Visual Studio, Form, Label Disabled but keep ForeColor (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2015, label

I have a form in Visual Studio, one Label in the form needs to be disabled, (Under the Behavior category, `Enabled` set to `False`).

When the Label Behavior is set to "Enabled = False", the ForeColor of the Label changes to a gray color, when I run the application. If I want to keep the original color, how would I go about doing that?
The ForeColor that I want to use is White.

Comment: Why do you need to disable a Label? Labels are not interactive controls. Try changing the ForeColor when you consider your label is "disabled".

Comment: I soo knew that I would get this question... I even thought of explaining, but ignored it. The reason: I don't use the standard Windows Border for the Form, I have made my own panel that I can move around the form with. There is a label in the panel, and I can't drag the form if I hove over the label unless it is "disabled"

I tried changing the ForeColor when the Label is disabled, this doesn't work... It will still keep the Gray color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to inherit the `Label` class and then shadow the base `Enabled` property:

```
Public Class MyLabel : Inherits Label

    ' https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,eb7c3ce1cd1cb1d3
    Public Overridable Shadows Property Enabled As Boolean
        Get
            If (MyBase.Parent IsNot Nothing) Then
                Return MyBase.Parent.Enabled
            Else
                Return Me.enabledB
            End If
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            If (value <> Me.enabledB) Then
                Me.enabledB = value
                MyBase.OnEnabledChanged(EventArgs.Empty)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
    Private enabledB As Boolean ' Backing field

    Public Sub New()
        Me.enabledB = True
    End Sub

End Class
```